# Number string colours and trials. Need better solution

Tags: python

This is an excerpt from my full script (shortened so that it is more understandable).

I'm very much stuck at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do:

```
import random

# Build the question list
red =   ['1'] * 3 + ['2'] + ['3']
green = ['1'] + ['2'] * 3 + ['3']
blue =  ['1'] + ['2'] + ['3'] * 3

questions = []
questions.extend([('red', x) for x in red])
questions.extend([('green', x) for x in green])
questions.extend([('blue', x) for x in blue])

random.shuffle(questions)

for color, number in questions:
    # do whatever
```

This allows for you to pretty readily change the lists and it will auto-compile and shuffle them for you:

```
[1]*3+[2]+[3] generates [1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
```

Essentially: I want 3 1s, a 2 and 3 in a list.

`questions.extend` extends the questions list with whatever list you pass it, so I want to put them all together.

`[('red', x) for x in red]` is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) which says: Make a new list, but for every number in that earlier list, instead say it's ('red', x) where x is what the old list had.

Finally, `random.shuffle()` shuffles the list so the order is random.

**NOTE**: This method (`['1'] * 3 + ['2'] + ['3']`) of list generation is not safe for [mutable objects](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Data_Types#Mutable_vs_Immutable_Objects), but because strings are immutable, we're fine.

Comment: `extend`, not `append`. `append` will add the list as a single element, `extend` will add the elements of one list to the other.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Fixed, thanks. That's what I get for manually moving the code over instead of copying.

Comment: Hmm this looks good. I'm not sure it's exactly what I'm looking for though, although I'll give it a try. I'm quite new to python, so this code is very difficult to understand at the moment. I'm working with Psychopy if that helps.

Comment: @Anonypy I added more explanation

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a different approach: store the objects you want with *all* of their characteristics: display character and colour.  This gives you something like:

```
display_candidates = [
    ('1', 'r'), ('1', 'r'), ('1', 'r'),
    ('1', 'g'), ('1', 'b'),
    ('2', 'g'), ('2', 'g'), ('2', 'g'),
    ('2', 'b'), ('2', 'r'),
    ('3', 'b'), ('3', 'b'), ('3', 'b'),
    ('3', 'r'), ('3', 'g')
]
```

Now, you pull out a random display object with

```
import random

random.shuffle(display_candidates)
for number, colour in display_candidates:
```

Now, use **colour** for setColor, much as you've done above.

You'll need to slap a loop around this to make it run the desired number of times.

Does this get you moving?

Comment: this pseudo-code is not quite what he's asking for (each option once), unless you remove each choice as you choose it. Also, you can simplify your decider via `number, color = display_candidates[random.randint(0, len(display_candidates))]`

Comment: Right.  This was just for a start, but I forgot to do the removal; I'll add that.  I was trying to keep the technology flexible: hence the multi-line implementation.

Comment: alternatively, you can just use `random.shuffle(display_candidates)` then loop through them with `for candidate in display_candidates:` which is considerably cleaner.

Comment: Thanks again; you just blew away half of the edit, maybe five seconds before I submitted.  Everyone else, please up-vote @TemporalWolf's help on this.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a data structure that pairs the strings with the colors, and then put in the desired combinations. So something like:

```
import random
trials = [{'text': '1', 'color': 'red'},
         {'text': '1', 'color': 'red'},
         {'text': '1', 'color': 'red'},
         {'text': '1', 'color': 'green'},
         {'text': '1', 'color': 'blue'},
         {'text': '2', 'color': 'green'}]  # ... etc
random.shuffle(trials)
key_mapping = {'r': 'red', 'g':'green', 'b':'blue'}  # which keys means which color

for trial in trials:
    stimu.color = trial['color']
    stimu.text = trial['text']
    stimu.draw()
    ewindow.flip()

    response = event.waitKeys(keyList=key_mapping.keys())[0]  # get first response, only allow keys which have been mapped
    trial['correct'] = key_mapping[response] == trial['color']  # True if correct, False if incorrect
```

Notice also how I simplified the code for setting stimulus attributes and scoring response - partly made possible by a better data structure. Although a list of dictionaries seems like overkill here, you most likely want to add more info at a later stage (trial number, subject ID, reaction time, etc.) and then it becomes useful.

Comment: Note there is a trade-off in readability vs space/time complexity by moving to dictionaries instead of tuples, and given the application it's probably worth making it a dictionary. I would still advocate for letting the program build the dictionary for you instead of typing it all out.